# Is it possible to make flexible order by in @Query?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm making a project(basic shop) and currently i stuck on ordering(for example by price, name, etc.). I want to know is there any easy way to make 1 flexible query for many cases, using order by for my commodities. Cause with my code it's returning unordered list of objects.

So in this project i send request to the server after user chooses sorting type in the combo box element. After that my controller is selecting the way of ordering, it's calling the query and after that returns our objects.

Please help, and by the chance can you tell me what way of switch(order_type) is better, in Controller or Service Implementation?

P.S. i use switch cause if i send request to the server as [ http://localhost:9999/commodities/category-name/CPU/c.name%20asc ] controller only see c without .name asc, that's why i used switch for that.

Code:

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("commodities")
public class CommodityController {

@GetMapping("category-name/{name}/{order_type}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<CommodityDTO>> getCommodityByCategoryNameWithOrder(@PathVariable("name") String categoryName, @PathVariable("order_type") String order_type){
        List<CommodityDTO> byCategoryWithOrder;

        switch(order_type) {

        case "name_asc":
            byCategoryWithOrder = commodityService.getAllByCategoryNameWithOrder(categoryName, "c.name asc");
            break;

        case "name_desc":
            byCategoryWithOrder = commodityService.getAllByCategoryNameWithOrder(categoryName, "c.name desc");
            break;

        case "price_asc":
            byCategoryWithOrder = commodityService.getAllByCategoryNameWithOrder(categoryName, "c.price asc");
            break;

        case "price_desc":
            byCategoryWithOrder = commodityService.getAllByCategoryNameWithOrder(categoryName, "c.price desc");
            break;

        default:
            return null;
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<CommodityDTO>>(byCategoryWithOrder,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Service Implementation:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CommodityServiceImpl implements CommodityService{

    @Autowired
    private CommodityRepository commodityRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapperUtils objectMapperUtils;

    @Autowired
    private CloudinaryService cloudinaryService;

    @Override
    public List<CommodityDTO> getAllByCategoryNameWithOrder(String categoryName, String order_type){
            System.out.println("\n\n\n\nOrder type:\n"+order_type+"\n\n\n\n");
            return objectMapperUtils.mapAll(commodityRepository.findAllByCategoryNameWithOrder(categoryName, order_type), CommodityDTO.class);
        }

}
```

Repository:

```
    public interface CommodityRepository  extends JpaRepository<Commodity, Integer>{
    @Query("Select c FROM Commodity c "
                + "Join Category ct on c.category.id = ct.id "
                + "where ct.name = ?1 "
                + "order by ?2")
        List<Commodity> findAllByCategoryNameWithOrder(String categoryName, String order_type);
    }
```

Comment: First Of all,Ordering should be Performed on the front end side and not on the server side,due to which you are going to save DB calls
i.e
You just provide the data to front end and sorting should be done on the Client side,if at all there is some logic change or huge data is present then ordering data then ordering at server side is good,in that case also fetch the data and use java logic to order not the DB logic

Comment: Don't write your own query. Just add an `findByCategoryName(String name, Pageable pageable)`. In the `Pageable` you can specify the size and ordering you want.

Comment: @AyushGoyal Is it right to sort on client side? Cause if we model a situation where we have, for example 1000 products, with different prices and we request only 20 products using pages (which is always required for better user experience), according to your advice we will sort only in range of that 20 elements that we've got from 1st get request. So if we will sort by price, we won't actualy get the most expensive one, or the cheapest of our shop, but the one of that 20 objects we've got from the page request. And to avoid that we need to make a request with order by or SortedSet collection.

Comment: @Yurii Malskiy Correct,My Bad !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at using the QueryDSL extension for Spring data. This, in combination with the Spring Data web extension,  will allow you to filter the entities by any combination of properties and apply sorting and paging **without writing any code.**

Add the following to your config and your code will then look like the below:

`@EnableSpringDataWebSupport`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.type-safe

See here on how to set-up your project to support QueryDsl:

https://www.baeldung.com/querydsl-with-jpa-tutorial

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping("/searchCommodities")
public ResponseEntity<List<CommodityDTO>> findCommodities(
         @QuerydslPredicate(root = Commodity.class) Predicate predicate,Pageable pageable){

     return new ResponseEntity<List<CommodityDTO>> 
                (commodityService.getCategories(predicate, pageable), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**Service**

```
public class CommodityServiceImpl implements CommodityService{
    @Override
    public List<CommodityDTO> getCategories(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable){
        return objectMapperUtils.mapAll(commodityRepository.findAll(
                       predicate, pageable), CommodityDTO.class);
}
```

**Repository**

```
public interface CommodityRepository  extends JpaRepository<Commodity, Integer>, 
                     QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Commodity>{
    //no query methods required
}
```

You can now call with, for example:

```
/searchCommodities?name=someName&sort=someProperty

/searchCommodities?name=someName&someOtherproperty=xyz&sort=someProperty,desc&sort=someProperty,asc

/searchCommodities?name=x&name=y&name=z //name = x or y or z
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Use jOOQ instead if you want to write your own queries.
2. Use Spring Data query methods and pass as an additional parameter Sort object.

Comment: Thanks, found that option few minutes before your reply. Guess it's perfec for my solution. :)